# Terraform - Removing a resource from local state file

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

To create a new Terraform state file, I'm importing some legacy Azure resources into a Terraform configuration with a local state file. As expected, my import syntax is as follows:

```
terraform import <Terraform Resource Name>.<Resource Label> <Azure Resource ID>
```

Unfortunately, for one of my resources, I used the wrong Resource Label and had to rename it. I then performed a Terraform plan, but as the earlier Resource Label had already been written into the state file, the plan now displays the message that a resource will be destroyed when applied. Just to clarify, the resource with the corrected Resource Label is also written into the state file, so there's no danger of it being destroyed in Azure.

I however want to clean up the local state file by removing the orphaned resource, so when I ran a Terraform Plan, it reports that:

```
"No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration"
```

How can I do so safely without compromising my state file or the legacy resources?

Comment: [`terraform state rm ...`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html)

Comment: which is definitely the solution at this point, but also you could have `terraform state mv` before re-importing into the renamed resource.

Comment: Read up a bit on the terraform state rm earlier and thought that might be the best bet too. Just wasn't sure if it would do a thorough job of cleaning up the redundancy in the local state file. I'll definitely give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @[luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302), I tested the command in my environment after I imported a keyvault resource to my local state file and then tried to removed only the keyvault resource from terraform state and it was successful.

[image]

The resource is only removed from state file and it can be still found in portal.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Command: state rm - Terraform by HashiCorp](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html#example-remove-all-instances-of-a-resource)

Comment: That's really helpful AnsumanBal-MT. I did also manage to clean up my local state file with the Terraform state rm command successfully.