# how to delete a terraform state file when the azure resources are removed using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We are building a temp review app in terraform. Currently when review app is finished with the resources are destroyed with terraform using terraform apply -destroy. What i need to do is also remove the terraform state file for this infrastructure from the azure container. Could I use terraform -destroy to also remove the state file and how can i do this?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the state file? Even if it's there it contains only metadata after you run `terraform destroy`.

Comment: cos my boss asked me to lol as many review apps will be created i suppose to tidy it up

Comment: You can just switch back to using local backend.

Comment: You can use terraform taint if you want to recreate any particular resource, and then your terraform state file will store those and destroy the previous. I don't think deletion of state file is good in this case . Agreed with @Marko E

Comment: Hello @itye1970
 , did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else you can accept it for beneficial other community members for the similar query.

Answer (score 0):

***One of the workaround you can follow,***

***When we are using terraform destroy that time our resource detailed also  removed from `terraform.tfstate` by removing from portal itself.***

*So to remove any particular resource from `.tfstate` you can try something like below*;

*First would suggest you to after destroy the file list the state file you have then remove those*.
*This below command is used to get the available instances which are in state file.*

```
 terraform state list
```

***After listing those try with below which will remove from `.tfstate` file as mentioned by @*Ansuman Bal* i have also tried and it works fine*** .

```
terraform state rm "azurerm_resource_group.example"
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

**NOTE:-** ***This aforementioned cmdlts will remove the instance/resources from `.tfstate` file only not from portal. Only `terraform destroy` can do that***.

*For more information please refer this* **SO THREAD**| [***Terraform - Removing a resource from local state file***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69205194/terraform-removing-a-resource-from-local-state-file).